# Can instances of classes defined in a module (i.e. not top level) be pickled somehow?

Tags: python, class, instance, pickle, dill

According to the documentation, this is not possible. But I am wondering if there is a workaround to this.

It seems like a very arbitrary limitation that would mess up with the overall code structure

I tried temporarily moving my class to the top level and it worked as expected.

I tried following "solution 3" in the link below but that didn't seem to work:
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/i-can-pickle-local-objects-if-i-use-a-derived-class

I have the following folder structure:

```
MainModule.py
libraries
 |- class_A.py
 |- processor.py
```

`__main__` in processor.py is executed to create an instance of `class_A` (with data) and pickle it.

Code in processor.py

```
import dill as pickle
from class_A import Class_A

data = 4
instance_of_A = Class_A(data)

path: str = r"C:\Users\ErikJ.GiesenLoo\Desktop\2023\EvdVds\instance_A.pkl"
with open(path, "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(instance_of_A, file)
```

Code in class_A

```
class Class_A:
    data = 0
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

Code in MainModule:

```
import dill as pickle
from libraries.class_A import Class_A


path: str = r"C:\Users\ErikJ.GiesenLoo\Desktop\2023\EvdVds\instance_A.pkl"
with open(path, "rb") as file:
    instance_A = pickle.load(file)

    print(instance_A.data)
```

MainModule.py then tries to unpickle the saved data, but unpickling only works if I move class_A.py outside of the libraries folder.

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_A'
```

Comment: you are using the term "top level" in contrast with "in a module", so it really isn't clear what you mean. Can you please provide a [mcve] of exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've modified my question above to hopefully clarify what i mean (but in essence i am using "top level" in contrast with "in a module". Maybe i am misunderstanding something

Comment: How do you know that unpickling does not work if you don't move class_A.py?

Comment: I get the feeling you've misunderstood what it means for code to be in a module. Moving `class_A.py` out of the `libraries` folder doesn't mean the code stops being in a module.

Comment: All your classes are at the "top level". Top level means *in the global scope of a module*. I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding. But again, you really must provide a [mcve] (note, the code you provided would raise `NameErrors`)

Comment: But, it is clear you mean "in a submodule". There is no restriction about a class being defined in a submodule. But if you define a class inside of, say, a function, then instances of that class cannot be pickled. That is what that restriction is referring to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I understand now? I pickled the class in processor.py (by running its __name__ == "__main__") but tried to unpickle it in MainModule. I should do both operations from MainModule (call the function in processor.py from MainModule)

Comment: @ErikGiesen that should not matter. I suspect the way you are handling imports/packaging is the problem here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've updated the question to include imports. When i execute the code in processor first, and then in mainModule, I get the same error. If i then move the class_A module outside of libraries, i can run the code in mainModule without issues.

Answer (score 1):

So you are misunderstanding what the documentation is saying. By "not at the top level" it doesn't mean a submodule, it means something like:

```
def make_class():
    class A:
        pass
    return A

A = make_class()
a = A()
```

Although, I believe `dill` may be able to handle this, but definitely, the default `pickle` will not.

The issue you are encountering is that aren't packaging your project, and relying on the the [default behavior of the directory of the script script being added to the module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html).

`libraries.class_a.Class_A` is not the same as `class_a.Class_A`. When you pickle your class, it is being recognized as `class_A.Class_A`, when you try to unpickle it, there *is no such class*, only `libraries.class_A.Class_A`.

You should package and install (perhaps in editable mode) your project. Then you should use imports consistently.

The laziest approach is to explicitly set the PYTHONPATH.

Change the import in `processor.py` to:

```
 from libraries.class_A import Class_A
```

Then, supposing your working directory is the directory that contains `MainModule.py`, you should do:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python libraries/processor.py
```

To execute that script, and you should do:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python MainModule.py
```

To execute the main script (although that isn't really necessary, it is just for consistency's sake).